# Dropdown is not in theri position in html

Tags: html

i try to add dropdown in repeater it shows me drodown above in table where as i want to show in status column 
code in html

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0"
   cellspacing="0" id="results">
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand" runat="server">
       <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>

        <td>
         DocumentID
         </td>
     <td>
       DocName
         </td>
       <td>
      File Name
         </td>
       <td>
      Document
        </td>
       <td>
       Department
      </td>
    <td>
     Status

   </td>

     </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>

     <td>
     <asp:Label Id="DocId" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>
    </td>
   <td>
      <asp:Label Id="DocName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocName")%>
       </td>
     <td>
    <asp:Label Id="Uploadfile" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uploadfile")%>
      </td>
     <td>
    <asp:Label Id="DocType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocType")%>
    </td>
   <td>
   <asp:Label Id="DepType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepType")%>
    </td>
   <td>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
 Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />
  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ApproveID")%>
   </td>

  </tr>


   <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"
  Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server"

     EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown"

   DataTextField="ApproveType"

   DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true"

    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">

   <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected"
  Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

     <asp:ListItem Text="Approve"
     Value="1"></asp:ListItem>

     <asp:ListItem Text="Reject"
    Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </table>

     <asp:Label ID="apfi" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
 <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button4_Click" />

   </div>
  </div>
    </center>
  </div>
```

pleae have a look image below  how i solve this ...where is mistake?

but it shows me like this 
[image](http://i39.tinypic.com/108h94h.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that your `DropDownList` (and a `Label`) are between the `table` and `tr` elements, which is invalid HTML.  The result client-side would be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <span>...</span>
    <select>
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
</table>
```

There's no way to correctly render that because `span` and `select` aren't table row elements.

As for how to fix this, that entirely depends on how you *want* those elements to display.  What you've attempted isn't a meaningful layout, so what is the layout you're looking for?

For example, if you want those elements to display in a table cell at the end of the row, you need to add a cell for them:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
            <span>...</span>
            <select>
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want them to display outside the table (maybe to the right of it?) then they'd need to be outside the table and you can use CSS to position them.  (Alignment would be tricky, though.  If they're logically part of the table, which they seem to be given that they're in its repeater, then they should be part of the table itself.)

Table structures have to be structured like a table.

(Note: Any time you have rendering issues like this, the *first* thing you should do is [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org).  That would have identified specifically which parts are invalid and referenced the HTML specifications which define those parts.)

Comment: plz check the link i posted image also

Comment: @user2931015: Right, that image shows the result of your invalid markup.  Which is what I'd expect, since the behavior of invalid markup is undefined (and probably browser-specific).  There's no way to make your version work, you need to re-structure it into a valid table structure.

Comment: hm and i want to this dropdown in status column

Comment: i dont understand this code ....<span>...</span>
            <select>
                <option>...</option>
            </select>

Comment: @user2931015: Those HTML elements are what your `Label` and `DropDownList` server-side elements become when rendered to the client-side.  You *really* need to understand client-side HTML if you're going to be doing web development.  As for putting the `DropDownList` in the "status" column, just put it in the `td` element which corresponds to that column.  Right now you're putting it entirely outside of any table cells.  Since a table is *only* composed of cells, it has no way to render that.